# Github Desktop runs once after install on Windows 10 then will not open again after it's been closed

Tags: windows, github, github-desktop

I can't find any information on a fix for this.

I have reinstalled Github Desktop with compatibility options set for Windows 7 and 8, as well as set it to run in those same compatibility modes on the application itself.

I can use it once after install and everything works but after I close it, the next time I go to launch Github Desktop I get a popup from Windows asking me to:

"Choose an application from a list to open this file"

Answer (score 1):

Try, after uninstalling [GitHub Desktop](https://help.github.com/desktop/guides/getting-started/uninstalling-github-desktop/), to make sure there is no GitHub folder left in `%LocalAppData%\GitHub` and the `%AppData%\GitHub`.

Try again installing (with elevated privileges) GitHub Desktop after that clean uninstall process.

Comment: I removed Github Desktop again through add/remove programs.  I then cleared out the files you mentioned and reinstalled Github Desktop.  I ran it once, closed it, and now when I try to open it the cursor has a spinning circle blinking, and it shows github as a process in task manager.  However, it still never opens.  I have to reboot again to get right of the process I can't even kill it manually.

Comment: Very strange. Is there a AV (Anti-Virus) which could explain that? Or some network issue?